# How to get dates of selected Day for entire month?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to select a day say, Monday. Now i want get the dates of all the Mondays which fall in that month or between two selected dates(even better). 
Eg.

> Day selected: Monday
>
> Start Date: 1st March
>
> End Date: 30th April

This must get me dates of all the 8 Mondays which fall between these two dates. I am ready to use DropDownList or calendar or whatever is necessary to do this.
I am working with C#, Visual Studio 2010.

Comment: let's see an attempt...

Comment: @JW. I am using MS SQL Server 2008

Comment: @MitchWheat I do not even know where to begin. I added a Calendar Control but this would just give me a single date. I am a beginner so plz bear with me.

Comment: @JW. application level. I would insert the dates into database later though.

Comment: @MitchWheat sorry i did not understand the question. deleting all my comments...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
DateTime d1 = DateTime.Parse("03/01/2013");
DateTime d2 = DateTime.Parse("04/01/2013");

int days = (d2 - d1).TotalDays;

for (i = 0; i <= days; i++) {
    DateTime d = d1.AddDays(i);
    if ((d.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Monday)) {
        Console.WriteLine(d);   //dateList.Add(d);   <------ this could be a List<DateTime> or List<string>
    }
}

Output - M/dd/yyyy format
-------
3/04/2013
3/11/2013
3/18/2013
3/25/2013
4/01/2013
```

Comment: I am working with webforms. Your Code Works though. Btw what should i use to store the output dates? ArrayList? What do you suggest?

Comment: Also i do not want to hardcode MONDAY. User must be able to select day himself.

Comment: You can add it to a list e.g. `ArrayList, List<DateTime>, List<String>` etc instead of `Console.WriteLine` and bind it to a `DropdownList`. I think you should be able to figure out the rest

Answer (score 0):

That's really simple algorithm:

```
    public static List<DateTime> GetDayOccurrences(DayOfWeek day, DateTime from, DateTime to)
    {
        var results = new List<DateTime>();

        while (from <= to)
        {
            if (from.DayOfWeek == day)
            {
                results.Add(from);
                from = from.AddDays(7);
            }
            else
            {
                from = from.AddDays(1);
            }

        }
        return results;
    }
```

To make it a bit faster I move 7 days forward if current date is chosen day of week.

And usage of that method:

```
        var from = new DateTime(2013, 3, 1);
        var to = new DateTime(2013, 4, 30);

        List<DateTime> mondays = GetDayOccurrences(DayOfWeek.Monday, from, to);
```

Btw: there are 9 Mondays between 01/03/2013 and 30/04/2013:

```
2013-03-04
2013-03-11
2013-03-18
2013-03-25
2013-04-01
2013-04-08
2013-04-15
2013-04-22
2013-04-29
```

***UPDATE***

It can also be done this way, to remove `if` statements within a loop:

```
    public static List<DateTime> GetDayOccurrences(DayOfWeek day, DateTime from, DateTime to)
    {
        var results = new List<DateTime>();

        while(from <= to && from.DayOfWeek != day)
            from = from.AddDays(1);

        while (from <= to)
        {
            results.Add(from);
            from = from.AddDays(7);
        }

        return results;
    }
```

Comment: I do not just want the count i want to store the dates also. All 9 of them. Also user must be able to select day by himself.

Comment: That method returns `List<DateTime>` with all dates found!